# Game Opens then Stops Responding Python

Tags: python, pygame

Sorry for the bad title, if you think of a better one please tell me.

So I was asked to make a button that says a line from a video game. I attempted to have the while loop add 1 to a variable every time it looped through, then display the variable in the caption of the window. I did this so that I could see if it was looping, and really, what was going on. It showed a rapidly increasing number, then froze the computer (I had to restart the computer). I tried putting a short wait in the loop, still would not respond. I am also having this exact same problem in a much longer and more complex program that I'm working on, so if I figure it out, it will solve both issues. Don't just give me code, please tell me why I need to use it or what it does. Here's the program:

```
from pygame import *
import pygame
pygame.init()

pygame.display.set_caption('Potato')
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((224, 224))
button = pygame.image.load("C:/Python34/redbutton.jpg")
screen.blit(button,(0,0))
pygame.display.flip()

potato = pygame.mixer.Sound("C:/Python34/potato.wav")

test = 0
pressed = False

while pressed == False:
    if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[1]:
        pressed = True

    if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
        potato.play()

sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation for `pygame.mouse.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mouse.html#pygame.mouse.get_pressed):

> Note, remember to call [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get) before this function. Otherwise it will not work.

Comment: And while I'm on the topic, it also says *"it is better to use either `pygame.event.wait()` or `pygame.event.get()` and check all of (the accumulated) events"* instead of just testing whether the mouse button happens to be down at this particular moment.

Comment: No worries!  If this works for you, please upvote and/or accept the answer, so the site knows that the question's been answered.  :)

Comment: Sorry I didn't upvote earlier, it said I had to wait. Thanks!